# I have a Syntax error in JOIN operation error

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, web

So I've tried several variants to my SELECT statement and it keeps telling me either "Syntax error in JOIN operation" or "Invalid bracketing" or "Syntax error in FROM clause"

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON  Table2.ID=BlogEntryItem.BlogID WHERE ([ID]=@ID)">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Decimal" />                    
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
    runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="picTableStyle"
    DataKeyField="BlogTitle">
    <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Image") %>' /><br />
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="picCaptionStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>' />
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="picBodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PicStory") %>' />
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

I'm having a rough go at it. As you can see, I'm trying to pass the ID of a record in that ends up on my home page for my website, and using that to pull records from the "BlogEntryItem" table and pulling it into another page on my website and populating the page with those items. Does that make sense? Why isn't my JOIN working?

Comment: Can you post the value in SelectCommand?? And the command has some issues. Should be something like `SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON  Table2.ID=BlogEntryItems.BlogID WHERE ([ID]=@ID)`

Comment: You can't join on `BlogEntryItem.BlogID` unless you include a table named `BlogEntryItem` in the query.  `BlogEntryItem` <> `BlogEntryItems`

Comment: @HansUp What part of the query are you talking about? In my join statement,  I have "Table2 INNER JOIN BlogEntryItem" so that both tables are included in the join.

Comment: @Nilesh The value changes based on what is clicked on another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INNER JOIN **BlogEntryItems** ON  Table2.ID=**BlogEntryItem**. Forget something in table name

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax error.

Table2.ID = @ID

```
SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON  Table2.ID=BlogEntryItem.BlogID WHERE Table2.ID = @ID
```